# PHP Links Dynamics

Tags: php, hyperlink

I have to build a function for create clients. When I register a new client, each one of them should have its own detail page.

For Example, Coca Cola:  When I register "cocacola" client, I have to build a link: `www.dominio.com/cocacola`.
If the client is BMW, the link should be `www.dominio.com/bmw`.

I'm using PHP5, mysql, apache.

Any help?

regards,
barcelona23

Comment: You need to be more specific. What have you tried so far? Are you using any framework? MVC or not? Paste some code or some ideas, and we will try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case use mod_rewrite.  Example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?client=$1 [L]
```

This would take the first parameter and send it to the index.php page with the parameter client set to the client entered.

So the user would see this `www.dominio.com/cocacola` and behind the scenes would be this `www.dominio.com/index.php?client=cocacola`

Then in your index.php page you can access the set client by using `$_GET['client']`

Here is a good [tutorial on mod_rewrite](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/apache-mod_rewrite-examples)

Answer (score 3):

Feel free to checkout mod_rewrite.  It can rewrite a given URL to map to a script with query parameters.

http://dominio.com/DynamicPathPart  ==> http://dominio.com/yourscript.php?path=DynamicPathPart

From there it's just pure PHP.

To tame the beast that is mod_rewrite turn to a friendly tutorial.  Here's one I've used:

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/guide-url-rewriting